# Best way to load assets in android java

Tags: java, android, load, assets

I have one android activity with a lot of calculations and everything is ok, but in the final version of my project I need to load a lot of bitmaps and sounds in the same activity and it gets a lot slower than it should be.. Sometimes the activity chrashes itself.

So, is there any advice how should I load all the assets? Should I declare them in separate class, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you only load those assets when you need them and unload them if you do not need them. (Lazy Loading)

Because mobile has limited memory and I am imagining your files are really big you must be careful on how you will manage those files.

For image I recommend this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) and try to optimize your [image as good as possible](http://imageoptim.com/)

For sounds kindly look at this [class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) and this discussion [about loading sound files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289038/play-audio-file-from-the-assets-directory)

[OutOfMemoryError when loading large amount of data in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529586/outofmemoryerror-when-loading-large-amount-of-data-in-android)

[Android SoundPool – How to check if sound file is loaded?](http://blog.vogella.com/2011/06/27/android-soundpool-how-to-check-if-sound-file-is-loaded/)